# How to break the line inside the brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to be able to break the line inside the brackets without having the "inconsistant brackets" error.

Here's a example:

```
select.someclass.something{data: {max_amount: o.max_amount_clean, max_amount: o.min_amount_clean, fee: o.fee_clean}}
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you break it ? You may need a \ as continuation character.

Comment: Is this meant to be a Haml statement? Don’t you mean `%select.someclass...`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand, but if the argument is a hash and not a block, like it seems, you could do

```
select.someclass.something(
  {data: 
      {max_amount: o.max_amount_clean, 
       max_amount: o.min_amount_clean, 
       fee: o.fee_clean}}
)
```

Comment: I've got an "Invalid attribute list" error

Comment: like others said, the question is too vague to understand. Is it Ruby or haml? 

A general approach, when asking a technical question, is 
to try to find a minimal situation where the issue manifests, which is crucial in isolating the problem.